# What is the push command doing in this perl code

Tags: perl

I am converting some old Perl code to JavaScript and I am a little confused with one line in the example below.

**PERL CODE - Part of a class:**

```
sub add {
  # account, amount, description, [journal], [company],
  # [date], [control], [document], [reference], [source]
  my $class = shift;
  my ($par) = @_;

  my $self;
  $self->{JOURNAL} = SeekValue($par, $class->journal, 'journal', 'type', 'typ');
  $self->{COMPANY} = SeekValue($par, $class->company, 'company', 'co', 'com');
  $self->{DATE} = SeekValue($par, $class->date, 'date', 'dat');
  $self->{CONTROL} = SeekValue($par, $class->control, 'control', 'con', 'cont', 'ctl');
  $self->{DOCUMENT} = SeekValue($par, $class->document, 'document', 'doc');
  $self->{REFERENCE} = SeekValue($par, $class->reference, 'reference', 'ref');
  $self->{SOURCE} = SeekValue($par, $class->source, 'PL', 'source', 'src');

  # Required fields.
  my $amount = conv_amount(SeekValue($par, undef, 'amount', 'amnt', 'amt'), 2);
  return 0 unless abs($amount); # Don't add this transaction if there isn't an amount.
  $self->{ACCOUNT} = $amount;
  $self->{AMOUNT} = SeekValue($par, undef, 'account', 'acct', 'act');
  $self->{DESCRIPTION} = SeekValue($par, undef, 'description', 'desc', 'des');

  bless $self;
  push(@{$class->{DOCUMENTS}->{$self->{DOCUMENT}}}, $self);
  return 1;
}
```

I THINK what it is doing is:

- Getting the class instance `$class`
- getting the incoming parameter `$par`, which was passed in as an object
- Creating a new object `$self`
- Copying values out of `$par` into `$self` (SeekValue is used to allow differing property names)
- `bless $self` Still not sure what this really does
- Then I don't really know what the `push` is doing. Is it adding the new copy of `$self` into the property `$DOCUMENTS` of the current instance of the class?

The last line is my question. What is the push doing? And what is it affecting?

Comment: `bless $self;` is what create an object (in the instance-of-class sense, not the confusing term JS uses for associative arrays). Since they forgot to pass `$class` as the second argument, it creates an object of class `main`.

Comment: This file does have `package OWI::Arkona;` at the top. Would it use that as the class, or would it still use `main`?

Comment: My bad, `OWI::Arkona`

Comment: Re "*would this be a valid translation*", Not sure. Depends on whether `this.DOCUMENT` is a string or not. JS objects can only have strings for keys. Same with Perl hashes, but the stringifications might be different in the two languages. Otherwise, most likely yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```perl
push @{ $class->{DOCUMENTS}->{ $self->{DOCUMENT } } }, $self;
```

can also be written as

```perl
if (!defined($class->{DOCUMENTS})) {  # Probably already exists.
   $class->{DOCUMENTS} = {};
}

my $documents = $class->{DOCUMENTS};

if (!defined($documents->{ $self->{DOCUMENT} })) {
   $documents->{ $self->{DOCUMENT } = [];
}

push @{ $documents->{ $self->{DOCUMENT } } }, $self;
```

It's adding a reference to the newly constructed object to an array. That array is referenced by an associative array (hash in Perl, object in JS) keyed by the document. The array is created if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: So `$class->{DOCUMENTS}->{$self->{DOCUMENT}}` is using the value of `$self->{DOCUMENT}` as the key in the hash of an array and `$self` as the value to push into the array? Also this code didn't every subclass so that would not have been a problem.

Comment: No, the value of the hash is an array. See update.

Comment: Would `$self->{DOCUMENTS}` in Perl be like `self.DOCUMENTS` in JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, and I have already changed my answer to reflect that. I initially assumed `$class` was a string, but that's probably not the case. (Constructors, which this kinda is, normally expect a string consisting of a class name as their first argument, and the parameter is often named `$class`.)

Comment: The constructor is a different function. But I think I am getting this now. Your help has been greatly appreciated. This in Perl `$documents->{$self->{DOCUMENT}} = [];` should be like this in JS `documents[$self.DOCUMENT] = [];` assuming that `$self.DOCUMENT` is a string, which it is.

Comment: Is this valid in Perl: `$documents->{$self->DOCUMENT} = [];` I removed the set of `{}` around `DOCUMENT`. If it is, in this example, when would I want to use `{}` and when wouldn't I? Reading this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_object_oriented.htm it looks like I should always use `{}` around the fieldname.

Comment: It is valid Perl, but `$self->DOCUMENT` is a method call, while `$self->{DOCUMENT}` is a hash lookup.

Comment: Perfect. THANK YOU!!